# Customizing Navigation in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I need to customize my sharepoint site main top menu bar.

Main Menu Navigation : Primary navigation. It should have all the main tabs. If a user clicks on any tab then the subsites under the selected tab should be displayed as secondary navigation. By clickin on any link in secondary tab section the link for that selected tab should be displayed in a drop down as tertiary navigation.

I need to customize the sharepoint site for this. Can anybody have the better idea for this. It would be grateful even links provided.

Thanks in advance

Comment: helloo. can anybody answer it??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sorry this has not been answered. This solution utilizes their built in sharepoint navigation and allows you to customize the menu however you wish.

http://sharepoint2010customnavigation.blogspot.com/